# How to get a attribute value of another element in button click in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have image tag and button , I want to get the `imgid` attribute value on button click

This is my html code :

```
<img class="thumb" ng-model="add_new_ads_mdl.img_add" imgid = "{{data._id}}" src="{{data.url}}" />
<span><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="close_img(add_new_ads_mdl.img_add.imgid)"></i></span>
```

and I try it in angular like this :

```
$scope.close_img = function(item)
{
        console.log(item); // Undefined
}
```

But I get undefined only. Can anyone help me please .. thanks a lot in advance ...

Comment: Just pass `data._id` in `close_img()` like `close_img(data._id)`

Comment: ng-click="close_img(data._id)"